# Arrow key mappings do not function

Tags: vim, terminal, shortcut

Well,

One can use `<C-w>[hjkl]` to move between window, and it's works!

Then I shortcut the horizontal moves like `noremap <S-RIGHT> <C-W>l`, and it's works!

But, when I try to shortcut the vertical moves, I use `noremap <S-UP> <C-W>k` and `noremap <S-DOWN> <C-W>j`, and it **doesn't work!**

Any suggestions?

**EDIT** : Assuming than the terminal handles the `<S-UP> and` `<S-DOWN>`, which conflict with my vim (or whatever term app) preferences, is there any way to force the terminal to forget this mapping ??

Comment: "when coming the lateral rotated by pi/2" Not sure what is meant by this.

Comment: In the assumtion that lateral is left/right sides, lateral rotated by pi/2 is the lateral up/down sides. Does it make sense ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [VIM Custom arrow key mappings not working with window switching?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21460514/vim-custom-arrow-key-mappings-not-working-with-window-switching)

Comment: Ok, so maybe the S-UP/DOWN is handled by console, but it 's not in /etc/inputrc neither in desktop's shortcuts... So I don't know how to make it up ? Basically it seems to sroll up by one line the terminal

Comment: What does it do when you try using your up/down mappings? "Doesn't work" isn't very descriptive. Does nothing happen? Does Vim beep? Does it enter insert mode instead? What happens?

Comment: Not all terminals can handle every key codes. Arrow keys, shift, alt, and some control key presses are not always distinguishable. You might want to try out some different keys. I would also recommend using `nnoremap` instead of `noremap`